# Run check before tests

Tags: scala, playframework

I have tests which are run against a real database (not an in-memory or mocked up one).  Before the tests run, I want to check the environment variables to make sure that the TEST database is not the same as the PROD database.  If they do match I want to stop the tests.

I thought I could do something like this:

```
class Main extends Suites (
    new EnvironmentTest,    // This needs to run first!!
    new Tests1,
    new Tests2,
    new Tests3
)

@DoNotDiscover
class EnvironmentTest extends PlaySpec {

    "Environment variables" should {
        "PROD SQL DB should be different from TEST SQL DB" in {
            // Do check and stop execution 
            throw new EnvironmentVariableException("TEST and PROD are the same!")
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, the exception is thrown and the first test fails, but the rest of the tests will run.

Is it possible to stop the execution of the tests (or do a check before hand to prevent them from running at all) ?